# Error when fetching pending voters from smart contract using ethers.js

Tags: reactjs, solidity, metamask, ethers.js, hardhat

I am developing a voting application using React.js, ethers.js, and a Solidity smart contract. The application allows users to register as voters, and the admin can approve or reject pending voters. However, when I try to fetch the list of pending voters from the smart contract, I encounter an error in the console:

```
PendingVotersPage.js:22 Failed to fetch pending voters: Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [], "key": "pendingVoters" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.11.1) at makeError (errors.ts:694:1) at assert (errors.ts:715:1) at getFragment (contract.ts:270:1) at Proxy.pendingVoters (contract.ts:350:1) at VotingService.callContractMethod (VotingService.js:39:1) at async fetchPendingVoters (PendingVotersPage.js:16:1)
```

PendingVotersPage.js

```
const fetchPendingVoters = async () => {
    try {
        const voterAddresses = await VotingService.getPendingVoters();
        const voterDetails = await Promise.all(
            voterAddresses.map((address) => VotingService.getVoter(address))
        );
        setPendingVoters(voterDetails);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch pending voters:', error);
    }
};
```

VotingService.js

```
async getPendingVoters() {
    return this.callContractMethod('pendingVoters');
}
```

Solidity.sol

```
address[] public pendingVoters;

function getPendingVoters() public view returns (address[] memory) {
    return pendingVoters;
}
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:
Deploy the smart contract
Register some voters using the registerVoter function
Navigate to the PendingVotersPage component in the React application
Observe the error in the browser console
Expected behavior: The PendingVotersPage should fetch the list of pending voters from the smart contract and display their details in a table.
Actual behavior: The application fails to fetch the pending voters and throws the mentioned error in the console.
Environment:
React.js version: 18.2.0
ethers.js version: 6.11.1
Solidity version: 0.8.24
Browser: Google Chrome
I have tried to debug the issue by adding console logs and breakpoints, but I couldn't figure out the root cause of the problem. I would appreciate any help or guidance in resolving this issue and successfully fetching the pending voters from the smart contract.